# what do $$PWD and . mean in .pro in qt

Tags: qt, qmake

I came across a lib missing problem in my app, it turns out that this might relate to my understanding of `$$PWD` and `.` in .pro file of qt project.

1. So do `$$PWD` and `.` both mean **the dir, which contains the .pro file** OR **the dir, which is generated by building process(like: ****-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Debug)**. Or, they mean different things.
2. in some variable declaration like `OBJECTS_DIR = obj/Obj`, it looks like that `.` means the **generated dir**.  Whereas, in `HEADERS  += remoteclient.h ./RealPlay/realplay.h \`, it looks like that `.` means **the dir that contains .pro file**.
3. How about their meanings in LIBS and DESTDIR, etc. ?

Comment: The respective dir in the build directory is `$$OUT_PWD`. You can debug such things with `message(“PWD=$$PWD")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$$PWD` means the dir where the current file (.pro or .pri) is.

It means the same in `LIBS`. I just used it like this in my project:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/deps/android -lopenal
```

`.` doesn't have any special meaning in the .pro file. It means the same thing as in Linux/Unix shell: the current working directory. If you use it in `LIBS`, it will most probably refer to the build directory where the link command is being run. `.` is not expanded. If you say `-L.` the linker will literally get `-L.`

In the case of `HEADERS += remoteclient.h ./RealPlay/realplay.h \` qmake will treat these paths relative to `$$PWD` so it doesn't matter if there's `.` or not. `HEADERS += $$PWD/remoteclient.h $$PWD/./RealPlay/realplay.h \` would be the effective search paths in this case. Otherwise out-of-source builds wouldn't work.

Note that `.` in the middle of a path doesn't do anything.

Comment: so in case `OBJECTS_DIR = obj/Obj` , you mean it actually means `$$PWD/obj/Obj` ? But the truth is it's in the build dir, - namely - say `.../Linux32/****-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Debug/obj/Obj` where the `.pro` file locates in `.../Linux32/QtCreator/`. I'm still a little confusing here

Comment: I didn't say anything about OBJECTS_DIR. It might be relative to the build dir :)